# I want to extract version from text file from certain line and use it as a command

Tags: text-processing, json

For example my text in the file "somefile.json":

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "name1": "text1#version1",
    "name2": "text2#version2",
    "name3": "text3#version3"
  },
  "wont-need-to-get-versions-from-here": [
    {
      "randomtext": "randomtext",
      "randomurl": "randomurl",
      "scopes": [
        "randomscope"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I would like to get `"version2"` with the help of `"name2"`, and use it afterwards as an extension of the command, for example if command was `"command"`, after getting `"version2"` it should be `"command#version2"`. Maybe this command and extracted `"version2"` should be written to some .sh file afterwards? (Sorry if this is a stupid question)

Comment: it is a .json yes

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I updated the text

Comment: Thanks so to be clear we want to strip the `text2` part of the value?  Will the text and version always be delimited by a `#`?

Comment: Yes # will always be there and yes we want to strip "text2" for example

Comment: Sorry I think I misunderstood the question, we want to extract `"version2"` from the text and use it as an extension of a command,(I need that to pull certain branch from github and not from the master)

Comment: So you could extract that value with something like `<somefile.json jq -r .dependencies.name2`.  But it will include `text2#version2`.  You could then use something like sed, awk, or even parameter expansion to remove that unwanted part but I'm sure that can also be done right in jq itself (I just don't know how).

Comment: @jesse_b `jq` has some built-in text manipulation capabilities - for example you could `split` the string on `#` and take the last value: `jq -r '.dependencies.name2 | split("#")[-1]'` or `jq -r '.dependencies.name2 | split("#") | last'`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the strings `name2` and `command` are the two inputs to the command that you're looking for and that, given the document in the question, you want to get out the result `command#version2` from a query with these strings.

The `jq` command is used to query or modify a JSON document.  The command below extracts the value from the `dependencies` sub-object whose key corresponds to the string `name2` (or whatever is given as the string in the shell variable `key`).  It replaces the value part before the first `#` character with `command` (or whatever is given in the shell variable `cmd`).  The resulting string is decoded if needed and printed to the standard output stream.

```bsh
key='name2'
cmd='some command'

jq -r --arg key "$key" --arg cmd "$cmd" \
    '.dependencies[$key] // empty | sub("^[^#]*"; $cmd)' somefile.json
```

Given the document in the question, the above would generate

```
some command#version2
```

If no key in the `dependencies` sub-object matches the given `$key` value, the command will produce no output.

Answer (score 0):

Get the value `text2#version2`:

```bsh
jq -r '.dependencies.name2' somefile.json
```

```
text2#version2
```

Cut the second field `version2`:

```bsh
jq -r '.dependencies.name2' somefile.json | cut -d# -f2
```

```
version2
```

Execute the command `command#version2`:

```bsh
exec command#$(jq -r '.dependencies.name2' somefile.json | cut -d# -f2)
```

You can replace `exec` with `eval` if you want to keep the shell process.